# error NG8001: 'nz-layout' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

Every thing I copied from NG-ZORRO, I also imported NgZorroAntdModule, but when I'm trying to build the project I encountered this error.

ERROR in pages/welcome/welcome.component.ts:8:5 - error NG8001: 'nz-layout' is not a known element:

1. If 'nz-layout' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nz-layout' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Below is my code:
WelcomeModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { WelcomeRoutingModule } from './welcome-routing.module';

import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {AppModule} from '../../app.module';
import { NzGridModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/grid';
import { NzLayoutModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/layout';
import {NzMenuModule} from 'ng-zorro-antd/menu';
import {NzBreadCrumbModule} from 'ng-zorro-antd/breadcrumb';
import {NgZorroAntdModule} from '../../ng-zorro-antd.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [WelcomeRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppModule,
    NzLayoutModule,
    NzGridModule,
    NzMenuModule,
    NzBreadCrumbModule,
    NgZorroAntdModule],
  declarations: [WelcomeComponent],
  exports: [WelcomeComponent]
})
export class WelcomeModule { }


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { components } from '../../model/componentMapping';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome',
  template: `
    <nz-layout>
      <nz-header>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul nz-menu nzTheme="dark" nzMode="horizontal" class="header-menu">
          <li nz-menu-item nzSelected>nav 1</li>
          <li nz-menu-item>nav 2</li>
          <li nz-menu-item>nav 3</li>
        </ul>
      </nz-header>
      <nz-layout>
        <nz-sider nzWidth="200px" nzTheme="light">
          <ul nz-menu nzMode="inline" class="sider-menu">
            <li nz-submenu nzOpen nzIcon="user" nzTitle="subnav 1">
              <ul>
                <li nz-menu-item nzSelected>option1</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option2</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option3</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option4</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li nz-submenu nzTitle="subnav 2" nzIcon="laptop">
              <ul>
                <li nz-menu-item>option5</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option6</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option7</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option8</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li nz-submenu nzTitle="subnav 3" nzIcon="notification">
              <ul>
                <li nz-menu-item>option9</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option10</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option11</li>
                <li nz-menu-item>option12</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nz-sider>
        <nz-layout class="inner-layout">
          <nz-breadcrumb>
            <nz-breadcrumb-item>Home</nz-breadcrumb-item>
            <nz-breadcrumb-item>List</nz-breadcrumb-item>
            <nz-breadcrumb-item>App</nz-breadcrumb-item>
          </nz-breadcrumb>
          <nz-content>Content</nz-content>
        </nz-layout>
      </nz-layout>
    </nz-layout>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  isCollapsed = false;
  size64 = '64';
  size32 = '32';
  title = 'Welcome to use iTool Online';
  subTitle = '';
  routerPath = '';
  components = components;

  constructor() { }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Definition of NgZorroAntdModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { NzAffixModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/affix';
import { NzAlertModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/alert';
import { NzAnchorModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/anchor';
import { NzAutocompleteModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/auto-complete';
import { NzAvatarModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/avatar';
import { NzBackTopModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/back-top';
import { NzBadgeModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/badge';
import { NzBreadCrumbModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/breadcrumb';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';
import { NzCalendarModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/calendar';
import { NzCardModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/card';
import { NzCarouselModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/carousel';
import { NzCascaderModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/cascader';
import { NzCheckboxModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/checkbox';
import { NzCollapseModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/collapse';
import { NzCommentModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/comment';
import { NzNoAnimationModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/core/no-animation';
import { NzTransButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/core/trans-button';
import { NzWaveModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/core/wave';
import { NzDatePickerModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/date-picker';
import { NzDescriptionsModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/descriptions';
import { NzDividerModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/divider';
import { NzDrawerModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/drawer';
import { NzDropDownModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/dropdown';
import { NzEmptyModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/empty';
import { NzFormModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/form';
import { NzGridModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/grid';
import { NzI18nModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/i18n';
import { NzIconModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/icon';
import { NzInputModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/input';
import { NzInputNumberModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/input-number';
import { NzLayoutModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/layout';
import { NzListModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/list';
import { NzMentionModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/mention';
import { NzMenuModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/menu';
import { NzMessageModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/message';
import { NzModalModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/modal';
import { NzNotificationModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/notification';
import { NzPageHeaderModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/page-header';
import { NzPaginationModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/pagination';
import { NzPopconfirmModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/popconfirm';
import { NzPopoverModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/popover';
import { NzProgressModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/progress';
import { NzRadioModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/radio';
import { NzRateModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/rate';
import { NzResultModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/result';
import { NzSelectModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/select';
import { NzSkeletonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/skeleton';
import { NzSliderModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/slider';
import { NzSpinModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/spin';
import { NzStatisticModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/statistic';
import { NzStepsModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/steps';
import { NzSwitchModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/switch';
import { NzTableModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/table';
import { NzTabsModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tabs';
import { NzTagModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tag';
import { NzTimePickerModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/time-picker';
import { NzTimelineModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/timeline';
import { NzToolTipModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tooltip';
import { NzTransferModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/transfer';
import { NzTreeModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tree';
import { NzTreeSelectModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tree-select';
import { NzTypographyModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/typography';
import { NzUploadModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/upload';
import { NzResizableModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/resizable';
import { NzPipesModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/pipes';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    NzAffixModule,
    NzAlertModule,
    NzAnchorModule,
    NzAutocompleteModule,
    NzAvatarModule,
    NzBackTopModule,
    NzBadgeModule,
    NzButtonModule,
    NzBreadCrumbModule,
    NzCalendarModule,
    NzCardModule,
    NzCarouselModule,
    NzCascaderModule,
    NzCheckboxModule,
    NzCollapseModule,
    NzCommentModule,
    NzDatePickerModule,
    NzDescriptionsModule,
    NzDividerModule,
    NzDrawerModule,
    NzDropDownModule,
    NzEmptyModule,
    NzFormModule,
    NzGridModule,
    NzI18nModule,
    NzIconModule,
    NzInputModule,
    NzInputNumberModule,
    NzLayoutModule,
    NzListModule,
    NzMentionModule,
    NzMenuModule,
    NzMessageModule,
    NzModalModule,
    NzNoAnimationModule,
    NzNotificationModule,
    NzPageHeaderModule,
    NzPaginationModule,
    NzPopconfirmModule,
    NzPopoverModule,
    NzProgressModule,
    NzRadioModule,
    NzRateModule,
    NzResultModule,
    NzSelectModule,
    NzSkeletonModule,
    NzSliderModule,
    NzSpinModule,
    NzStatisticModule,
    NzStepsModule,
    NzSwitchModule,
    NzTableModule,
    NzTabsModule,
    NzTagModule,
    NzTimePickerModule,
    NzTimelineModule,
    NzToolTipModule,
    NzTransButtonModule,
    NzTransferModule,
    NzTreeModule,
    NzTreeSelectModule,
    NzTypographyModule,
    NzUploadModule,
    NzWaveModule,
    NzResizableModule,
    NzPipesModule,
  ]
})
export class NgZorroAntdModule {

}
```

this is my structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaG7A.png)

Comment: Could you show how the `NgZorroAntdModule` module is defined?

Comment: Yes, below is the definition for NgZorroAntdModule

Comment: Sorry, I added in the main body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I resolved this issue.
This is because the Route configuration, it should be used with loadChildren, NOT use component

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule)}
];
```

Previously, it was like below, this is NOT correct:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'pages', component: PagesComponent }
];
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Would you please elaborate why you can resolve it like this?

Comment: @Henry Can you please elaborate why using 'component:xyz' is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

**Register the components in declarations of your app.module**

```
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, PagesComponent],
   ...
 })
```